# org-mode messing up a URL from Outlook Web

Tags: emacs, outlook, org-mode

I have a Zapier zap that takes an Outlook email from a folder, and appends a text entry in an inbox.txt file in my Dropbox, which I then convert to inbox.org.    The text entry has the email subject as the TODO headline, and the note has the Outlook email URL from Zapier plus a body preview.
When I click on the URL link in org-mode, it does not work.  For some reason, org-mode is screwing up the URL when it passes it my Chrome browser (I am on a Mac, using the latest Emacs for Mac version).

Here is an example.  The "GOOD" URL is what is actually in the inbox.org file as seen in Emacs.  If I manually copy and paste that URL into Chrome, no problem.  But, if I simply click on the URL in Emacs, the "BAD" URL is what appears in the browser.  Notice how some characters are different.

**Anyone have clue?** . I also use Beorg on iOS, and it correctly opens the link on my iPhone.

GOOD
`https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADI2ZGEzMWMzLTVkOTItNGRkOS04ZjkzLTVmODUzNDZhMjE3OABGAAAAAACfpz95dsWeQ5i6qmcPiDh6BwC6Rj4Y9RfWRZ26IgJTOwZ1AAMJ4B%2BqAAC6Rj4Y9RfWRZ26IgJTOwZ1AAMUEGjBAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem`

BAD
`https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADI2ZGEzMWMzLTVkOTItNGRkOS04ZjkzLTVmODUzNDZhMjE3OABGAAAAAACfpz95dsWeQ5i6qmcPiDh6BwC6Rj4Y9RfWRZ26IgJTOwZ1AAMJ4B+qAAC6Rj4Y9RfWRZ26IgJTOwZ1AAMUEGjBAAA%3d&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem&exvsurl=1&path=`

Answer (score 0):

I assume this has nothing to do with Orgmode itself, but how your browser interprets the url you hand over from emacs. The "plus" sign is not encoded (%2B) and therefore your Browser does not just leave the "plus" sign in the url but interprets it and normally turns it into a space.

Comment: Understood.  Is there a solution to this to have my links in org-mode (emacs) just work?